# Low/High Pass Filters

Tags: cordova, filter, lowpass-filter

I am creating an android phonegap application that detects road surface irregularities such as potholes and speed bumps.  I am relying on the accelerometer values provided by the phone through phonegap and will use the values to do some processing.

However, since the values are rather rough, I wanted to use some kind of filtering to smooth down the values.  I am aware that there are low and high pass filters.  But what is the difference between them? And how would using one rather the other in my application affect the smoothness and reliability of the values?

Comment: this is not answer to ur question but accelerometer does not detect changes within the plane surface/orientation of the phone...

Comment: Is the information you're looking for not in http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Low-pass_filter and http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/High-pass_filter?

Comment: If you don't know such basic concepts of signal processing as high/low-pass filters, how are you going to analyze your data for those irregularities? For instance, how were you planning on distinguishing a road irregularity from the car motor being started?

Comment: @MattiVirkkunen I will be checking whether the x, y and z values exceed certain thresholds

Answer (score 1):

It's perhaps a bit facile to say this, but the straightforward explanation is that low-pass filters allow low frequencies and reject/reduce high frequencies, and vice versa.

Smoothing normally involves rejecting high-frequency components.  You may be able to make progress with a couple of simple techniques:

1. Simple moving average (simply average the most recent *N* samples).
2. Exponential moving average (`y[n] = alpha * y[n-1] + (1 - alpha) * x[n]`).

See e.g. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moving_average for more info.

Choosing the value of the *N* or *alpha* parameter requires application-specific tuning.

However, proper filter design is a complex science/art.  For instance, rejecting high-frequency components will probably impair your ability to detect "real" events like potholes (they'll be smoothed out too).  You may start to need complex non-linear techniques such as thresholding.  But that's the subject of entire books!